# Reduce table length to certain number of characters

Tags: html, html-table

I want my description column (`job_field5`) to fit only 100 characters. I tried using length="n" but that didn't seem to work...

```
<table>
<tr> 
   <td>Date Posted</td>
   <td>Title</td>
   <td>Description</td>
   <td>Salary</td>
</tr>
[job_loop]
<tr>
   <td>[job_field8]</td>
   <td>[job_link][job_title][/job_link]</td>
   <td>[job_field5]</td>
   <td>[job_field1]</td>
</tr>
[/job_loop]
</table>
```

Comment: `length` is not even a valid attribute on a table cell... And I'm pretty sure this alone does not work. What JS library/php script are you using?

Comment: I don't know actually...this code is part of a wordpress theme. The description cells always range so I just want a standard of some sort...

Comment: The script is want you need to edit. I don't think this can be changed with just the template.